# Need to get the "id" attribute of <a> tag using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

My JSP has a tag whose id is getting populated dynamically:

```
c:forEach var="advisor" items="${advisors}">

<a  id="${advisor.getAdvisorId()}" href="#" onclick="GetAdvisorReview()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepay">img  src="assets/img/services/Icon_Reviews.png" width="50" alt="">/a>

</c:forEach>
```

JS:

```
function GetAdvisorReview(){
    var domElement =$(event.target);
    console.log(domElement.attr('id'));

    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    alert(this.id);
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Every alert is giving undefined.Please tell me what is wrong with the code.Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try using `this` inside the `onclick()`

```
<a  id="${advisor.getAdvisorId()}" href="#" onclick="GetAdvisorReview(this)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepay">img  src="assets/img/services/Icon_Reviews.png" width="50" alt="">/a>
```

And the Js should be:

```
    function GetAdvisorReview(e){
        alert(e.id); //Get the Id
    }
```

Where the `e` is the element that fired the event.

Comment: Or just, `e.id` - no need to wrap it in jQuery

Comment: Thanx Wilfredo..The code worked.Could you explain me what was wrong in my code.

Comment: you are not sending What Element is firing the event. With `this` you are sending the element as I said. thats all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the sender element and the event object, you should do this instead:

```
<a  id="${advisor.getAdvisorId()}" href="#" onclick="GetAdvisorReview(this, event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepay">img  src="assets/img/services/Icon_Reviews.png" width="50" alt="">/a>
```

Then you can access them like that:

```
function GetAdvisorReview(sender, e){
    alert(sender.id);
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Hi I used the above code: But Getting Uncaught ReferenceError: sender is not defined

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected my post. You have to put `this` instead of `sender` like this: `onclick="GetAdvisorReview(this, event)`

Answer (score 0):

Wilfredo P's  is a good approach, but I would suggest to avoid using inline JS by adding a CSS class to all your links and to use `addEventListener()` (pure JS) or `.on()` (jQuery) to bind the click event:

### JSP:

```
c:forEach var="advisor" items="${advisors}">

<a  id="${advisor.getAdvisorId()}" class="someClass" href="#" onclick="GetAdvisorReview()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepay">img  src="assets/img/services/Icon_Reviews.png" width="50" alt="">/a>

</c:forEach>
```

### Pure JS:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass");
for ( i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
    elems[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert( elems[0].getAttribute("id") );
    });
}
```

### jQuery:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someClass", this).on("click", function() {
        alert( $(this).attr("id") );
    });
});
```

### Demo:

```js
// Pure JS
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("someClass-js");
for ( i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
   elems[0].addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
     alert( this.getAttribute("id") );
   });
}

// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someClass-jquery", this).on("click", function() {
        alert( $(this).attr("id") );
    });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>With Pure JS:</p>
<a id="some-link-1" class="someClass-js" href="#">Some Link 1</a>
<a id="some-link-2" class="someClass-js" href="#">Some Link 2</a>
<p>With jQuery:</p>
<a id="some-link-3" class="someClass-jquery" href="#">Some Link 3</a>
<a id="some-link-4" class="someClass-jquery" href="#">Some Link 4</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have HTML markup errors in your loop.  I'm assuming those are SO
>   pasted typos only.  Otherwise, fix those as well as my code block displays.

An event listener solution is the approach I would take.

remove the onclick, replace it with a class:

```
 <c:forEach var="advisor" items="${advisors}">
    <a  id="${advisor.getAdvisorId()}" href="#" class="advisors" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#datepay">
      <img  src="assets/img/services/Icon_Reviews.png" width="50" alt="">
    </a>
 </c:forEach>
```

and then listen for that class click event to happen

```
$(".advisors").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pcx6csph/1/